# android - How to set MP3 as Ringtone

Tags: android-fragments

```
File newSoundFile = new File("pathFile");
        if (DebugUtil.DEBUG) {
            DebugUtil.logError(new Exception(), newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Title");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        try {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            KitKatToast.makeText(context, R.string.msg_setAsRingTuneSuccess, KitKatToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (DebugUtil.DEBUG) {
                DebugUtil.logError(new Exception(), e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw many posts but anyone showed what i should actually have to do. So i decided to create this complete answer. The only think you actually need is a button.
Lets start.

Here is my `MainActivity.java` which i used

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent1.setType("audio/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Choose Sound File"), 6);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 6) {
            Uri i = data.getData(); //getDATA
            String s = = i.getPath(); //getPath
            File k = new File(s); //set File from path

            if (s != null) { //(file.exists

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
                getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                try {
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly its really important to add those permisions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for example if you dont add the permision to write external storage your app will crash like mine.. xD

**What you need:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

You can try my app on Google Play : [BackAtel Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.backatel.volume)

Hope that helps.... my problem is now solved!! i hope that i solved your problem too :))